# Generic casting

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I have this generic class

```
public abstract class BaseExportCommand<T> where T : EditableEntity, new()
{
....
}
```

and I have this derived class

```
public class MessageExportCommand : BaseExportCommand<Message> 
{
 .....
}
```

Where Message inherits from EdittableEntity

```
public class Message : EditableEntity
{
...
}
```

Now, when I try to do this statement

```
BaseExportCommand<EditableEntity> myValue = new MessageExportCommand ();
```

I got the following error:

```
Cannot convert type 'MessageExportCommand' to 'BaseExportCommand<EditableEntity>'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Specifying the version of the CLR might be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

> Any idea why?

Yes. Your generic type isn't *covariant* in `T`.

We can't tell immediately whether it should be or not. For example, suppose it looked like this:

```
public abstract class BaseExportCommand<T> where T : EditableEntity, new()
{
    public abstract DoSomethingWithEntity(T entity);
}
```

Then suppose you could write:

```
BaseExportCommand<EditableEntity> myValue = new MessageExportCommand();
EditableEntity entity = new SomeEditableEntity();
myValue.DoSomethingWithEntity(entity);
```

... whereas `MessageExportCommand` only expects `DoSomethingWithEntity(Message)`.

It's safe if you're only using `T` as an *output* from `BaseExportCommand<T>`, but unfortunately C# doesn't let you declare covariant type parameters for classes - only for interfaces and delegates. So you could *potentially* write:

```
// Note the "out" part, signifying covariance
public interface IExportCommand<out T> where T : EditableEntity, new()
```

Then:

```
IExportCommand<EditableEntity> = new MessageExportCommand();
```

... but it depends on what members were declared in the interface. If you try to use `T` in any "input" positions, the compiler will notice and prevent you from declaring `T` covariantly.

See [Variance in Generic Types in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359.aspx) for more details, as well as [Eric Lippert's blog posts on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) (settle back and relax, there's a lot to read).

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if you declare `T` as co-variant:

```
public abstract class BaseExportCommand<out T> where T : EditableEntry, new()
{
    ...
}
```

Co-variant means, that you can use it for `T` or any class that inherits from `T`.

Also see the [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

Comment: Classes do not support co/contravariance.

Comment: ... and covariance is declared using `out`, not `in`.

Comment: Yeah, I always mix up `out` and `in`

Comment: @MathiasBecher: It's designed to be easy - if values only come *out* of the interface (e.g. return values) then you can declare it as `out`, and if they only go *in* (e.g. simple parameters) then you can declare it as `in`.